# How to compare permutations

Tags: c#, permutation, string-comparison

**Context**

I'm building an enciphering application (for fun) which is based on Enigma.

*(I put this question on codegolf.stackexchange.com but they said it was off topic and suggest here).*

Central to the design are virtual rotors (digital equivalents of the physical ones used in Enigma), where (in simple terms) a visible letter is mapped to a secret one.

For example, if the visible letters on a given rotor are A-Z, then we could describe the secret mappings like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ - A-Z
EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ - Rotor I
AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE - Rotor II
BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO - Rotor III
```

**The Question**

I have no problem generating new random mappings - but how could I compare them in terms of how similar they are?

What I want to do is generate a set of potential new rotor mappings and have some way of evaluating how similar they are, for example:

```
BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO - Rotor III
ZGFHJLCPRXTVDNYEIWBAMUKOQS - Random Rotor A
VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK - Random Rotor B
NYEIWGAKMUSQOBDFHJLCPRTXVZ - Random Rotor C
```

Compared to Rotor III, Random rotor A is different but B is visibly even more varied. Rotor C looks way different to Rotor III - but isn't, it's just Rotor III cut in half and the 2nd section put in front of the first.

How could I compare strings (or char arrays) of this nature?

FYI, I'd be using C# to build this, but happy to accept any decent logic that I can implement.

**Update**

The comparison doesn't have to be extremely precise.  The length of the strings will be longer than 26 - will vary somewhere around 100+, although all strings will be the same length.  The number of permutations will also vary but could be 100+.

Comment: Do you care about order or just how many of the characters match?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "different" and/or "similar". It seems like you're asking to see how many substrings of a certain length are contained in both strings. That's just a sequence of loops matching substrings. How many loops and what lengths you check determines how different or similar the strings are.

Comment: @maccettura - each mapping is a permutation of the same characters, the only difference is how they are arranged.  "order" i.e. sequence is relevant because the same order makes them too similar - see the random rotor C example compared to rotor III.

Comment: You could try summing the differences in the index of the character in the string (i.e. Rotor III [B] = 0 - Rotor C [B] = 13 = -13, and Rotor III [Q] = 24 - Rotor C [Q] = 11 = 13, -13 + 13 = 0, and so on for the other 24 letters).
Most of the time it would seem that the further the sum is from 0 the more "jumbled" the characters. Of course it could be crafted to work out to 0 in other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to simply write your own method to determine the similarity between two strings.

Here are a couple of ways you could consider the similarity, given that the strings will always be the same length and contain the same characters. One would be simply the percentage of characters that are in the same position, and the other would be the overall percentage of distance of all characters in the second string from their position in the first string.

The first one is pretty straight forward:

```
private static int GetSimilarity1(string first, string second)
{
    if (first == null) return second == null ? 100 : 0;

    // Set similarity to the percentage of characters in the same position
    var matches = first.Count(chr => first.IndexOf(chr) == second.IndexOf(chr));
    return (int)(matches / (decimal)first.Length * 100);
}
```

The second one would take the distance of each character in the second string from it's index in the first string and divide that by the maximum distance it could be from the index (the worst case). This will result in a low value (0) for an exact match, or a higher value the further it is away. Then, convert that number to a percentage by subtracting it from one (converting from a "bad" percent (0 for an exact match) to "good" percent (1 for an exact match)) and multiplying by 100. This number then gets added to a running total.

Finally, divide that total by the number of characters for the final "similarity" percentage.

To calculate the maximum distance a value could be from the actual position, I compare the value of it's index in the first array to the value of (length - index - 1), and whichever is bigger is the furthest possible index the character could be:

```
private static int GetSimilarity2(string first, string second)
{
    if (first == null) return second == null ? 100 : 0;

    int distance = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        var thisDist = Math.Abs(second.IndexOf(first[i]) - i);
        var worstDist = Math.Max(first.Length - i - 1, i);
        distance += (int)((1 - thisDist / (decimal) worstDist) * 100);
    }

    return distance / first.Length;
}
```

For testing these methods, I used the following code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var rotorIII = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
    var randRotorA = "ZGFHJLCPRXTVDNYEIWBAMUKOQS";
    var randRotorB = "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK";
    var randRotorC = "NYEIWGAKMUSQOBDFHJLCPRTXVZ";

    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: Rotor III -> Random Rotor A: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity1(rotorIII, randRotorA));
    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: Rotor III -> Random Rotor B: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity1(rotorIII, randRotorB));
    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: Rotor III -> Random Rotor C: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity1(rotorIII, randRotorC));

    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: Rotor III -> Random Rotor A: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity2(rotorIII, randRotorA));
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: Rotor III -> Random Rotor B: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity2(rotorIII, randRotorB));
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: Rotor III -> Random Rotor C: {0}", 
        GetSimilarity2(rotorIII, randRotorC));

    // Wait for input before closing
    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into the answer @Rufus L.  Let me try it out (may take a few days).

Comment: Sure, it was an interesting problem. Neither of them do the pattern matching you were looking for, though. Hope you find something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at using the Levenshtein distance. I think you are wrong, Rotor C is just as different as Rotor B, based on the result of using it to map the visible letters. What should matter in similarity/difference is the impact on the final output.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein